# Mongodb is taking almost 100% of CPU

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2

Good Morning,

I have installed `MongoDB` on an `EC2 machine` with 2CPU.

At the first time when I SSH Login I See this error message,

> System information disabled due to load higher than 2.0

However, My app is not receiving too many requests as before because of COVID it's receiving almost 30% of the normal traffic.

I tried to monitor the CPU usage and I got this `htop` :

[image]

and `mongostat` shows this

```
insert query update delete getmore command dirty  used flushes vsize   res qrw  arw net_in net_out conn                time
    *0     4     *0     *0       0     4|0  2.7% 93.3%       0 3.18G 2.20G 0|0 11|0  1.04k    121k   41 Mar 29 21:01:51.606
    *0    *0     *0     *0       0     4|0  2.7% 82.0%       0 3.18G 2.20G 0|0 11|0   285b   51.8k   41 Mar 29 21:01:52.737
    *0    *0     *0     *0       0     1|0  2.7% 86.0%       0 3.18G 2.20G 0|0 11|0   115b   42.3k   41 Mar 29 21:01:54.105
    *0    *0     *0     *0       0     6|0  2.7% 92.7%       0 3.18G 2.20G 0|0 11|0   462b    126k   41 Mar 29 21:01:54.566
    *0    *0     *0     *0       0     4|0  2.7% 86.5%       0 3.18G 2.20G 0|0 11|0   322b   58.5k   41 Mar 29 21:01:55.568
    *0     4     *0     *0       0     2|0  2.5% 88.3%       1 3.18G 2.20G 0|0 14|0   827b   54.6k   41 Mar 29 21:01:56.963
^C    *0
```

I see this data very very high and not realistic and I feel that there is something wrong with `MongoDB`, If you have any prior experiences with something like this please let me know

Comment: Have you checked the mongod.log file for the same period?

Comment: Yes. And everything is normal